# How to search sub-directories using GCC

Tags: gcc, include, include-path, gcc-warning

I have a top level folder `abc` which contains multiple folders. I don't want to provide every single path to headers in my different folders using `-I` gcc option. Is there a way through which gcc can search for header file in all subfolders of `abc` ?

Eg.

```
  abc
  |----abcd
        |----header1.h
  |----abce
        |----header2.h
  |----abcf
        |----header3.h
```

I want to include header1.h header2.h header3.h but don't want to use following approach

```
-I abc/abcd/
-I abc/adbe/
-I abc/abcf/
```

Is there a way through which I can just do `-<someflag> abc` and it searches whole subdirectories ?

Comment: Why don't you add the subdirectories to the include statements like `#include <abcd/header1.h>`? This would be the common approach. By this you only need to set the include path to the base folder `abc` and you have less ambiguity in your code.

Comment: @Markus I just gave here an example of nested folder structure. In real application it is more complicated and deep. So there are multiple folders , subfolders and multiple header files. So that approach doesn't look clean

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, gcc does not have anything like that. And for good reasons imho. What if there are two files with the same name but in different directories?

If using clang is an option, you can use `-Iabc/**`

Depending on what shell you're using, you could create a short shell script. Don't know if this fits your needs exactly, but it should probably be easy enough to modify:

```
dirs=""

for d in $(find -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -print0) 
do 
    dirs=$dirs"-I $d "
done

echo $dirs
```

You could use that in combination with assigning a variable in a Makefile. Let's call the above script `dirs.sh` and then use this in the Makefile:

```
INCLUDE_DIRS := $(shell ./dirs.sh)
```

Comment: This approach would work but not what I am looking for. Is there a way through which we can add an hack in makefile for this problem ?